# Laravel error "Missing required parameters for Route" when I use a form with a foreach loop

Tags: laravel, foreach, eloquent

> Missing required parameters for [Route: templates.answers.store] [URI: templates/{template}/answers]. (View: D:\Applications\xampp\htdocs\clientpad\resources\views\templates\answers.blade.php)

I am having the above error when I try and use a form with my foreach loop. I am not even sure why this is happening, maybe because I am new at Laravel. But this error goes away once I get rid of the AnswerController@store from the Eloquent form. It is possible I am doing this whole form wrong.

Here is what I want to do: A user made a template with questions, on the click of use button which goes to this url: http://clientpad.test/templates/{id}/answers they see their made questions which are shown with a foreach loop. Around it a Form is made so a user can answer the questions made. The form and answer field shows when I delete the action AnswerController@store, otherwise I get the above error.

Here is the code:

**AnswerController:**

```
    public function index(Template $template, Question $question)
        {
            $questions = $template->questions->mapWithKeys(function($question){
                return [$question->id => $question->question];
            });
            return view('templates.answers')->with('template', $template)->with('questions',$questions);
        }

   public function store(Request $request, Question $question, Answer $answer)
    {
        $answers = new Answer;
        $answers->answer = $request->input('answer');
        $answers->question_id = $request->input('question_id'); //current template id
        $question->answers()->save($answers);
        dd($question);
        return redirect('/dashboard')->with('success', 'Your Question Was Successfully Created');
    }
```

answers.blade.php

```
                {!! Form::open(['action' => 'AnswersController@store', 'method' => 'POST']) !!}               
                      @foreach ($questions as $question) <!-- Index counts the questions shown -->

                      <div class="panel panel-default">
                          <div class="panel-body">
                              <p class="pull-left question2"> {{$question}}</p>
                              <div class="form-group answer">

                            {{Form::label('', '')}}
                            {{Form::text('answer', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' => 'Type in your answer'])}}
                                </div>
                          </div>
                        </div>

                    @endforeach
                    <hr>
                         {{Form::submit('Save', ['class'=>'btn btn-primary'])}}
                    {!! Form::close() !!}
```

And I am just using the resource in routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are calling a route `templates/{id}/answers` in your Blade view that is missing the `{id}` parameter. Reading the error thoroughly will help you understand.

Instead of writing:

`Form::open(['action' => 'AnswersController@store', 'method' => 'POST'])`

You write:

`Form::open(['action' => ['AnswersController@store', $template_id], 'method' => 'POST'])`

The `$template_id` will fill the `{id}` in your route URL `templates/{id}/answers`.

Comment: That worked! I did not realise I was doing that wrong. Thank you so much! Although would you be able to help me understand why now the answer saves but without the id of the question? Its the same code as above.

Comment: Take a look at your `store()` function. You are setting the `question_id` by using data from the Form you created. It is totally ignoring the `{id}` in your URL. To confirm there is indeed an ID, inspect your HTML source code. Anyway, to use the ID from the URL, you can add another parameter to your `store()` function like `store($id...` and then do `dd($id);`, you will realize it is reading it from the URL. That's the bit that was missing --- an ID wasn't assigned to the URL.

Comment: So do I have to make sure the store isn't ignoring the template id from the url before I can get the question id? Would I be able to get it to save all 4 answers to their corresponding questions and their id's with one submit button? Sorry for all the questioning but you are very helpful

Comment: Actually, I was confused. My earlier comment is not 100% correct but at least you understand the relationship between the URL and how the route is formed. If it works right now for you... then it's fine as you are able to save all 4 answers to their questions' ids.

Comment: It saves the answer but the question id is null. I am not sure why when I do dd($question) it doesnt even seem to try and save the question_id, it does however say this:    0 => "question, template_id". It isnt acknowledging the question_id. Its strange cause this almost exact same method works for me with a different table.

Comment: Ah, your `store()` function will always have its $question and $answer as null. This is because your store() function will receive by default the `{id}` in your URL. Something like `store($id)` and doing `dd($id)` will print the ID. Something like `store($id, Request $request)` because of the `Request` type-hinting, will have Laravel inject the Request info enabling you to use `$request->input('question_id')`. Remove `Question $question, Answer $answer`.

Comment: I just realised that it isnt getting the id because i dont have a form field with it. It si simply being displayed as a p tag. How silly of me! I think if I input this into a hidden form and request it's id that should work!

Comment: I got it! basically I grabbed the whole database entry as an array and then chose what I want to show and what to save. Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: Anytime. Glad you sorted it out.